# Kinesis- like sharding with SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I'm interested in replacing Kinesis (because it's expensive and I don't need the historic log) with SQS, but I need a sharding/partitioning mechanism, specifically when processing with Lambda.

I see SQS FIFO queues have recently acquired Lambda event mapping -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/

which I think brings partitioning tantalisingly close via the use of `MessageGroupID`.

Message processing is described as proceeding via the following rules -

```
1) Return the oldest message where no other message with the same MessageGroupId is in flight.
2) Return as many messages with the same MessageGroupId as possible.
3) If a message batch is still not full, go back to the first rule. As a result, it’s possible for a single batch to contain messages from multiple MessageGroupIds.
```

1) and 2) sound great - each Lambda request batch containing a single MessageGroupID only - but then 3) seems to mess it all up :-(

Any thoughts on a strategy to ensure every Lambda request batch only contains messages from a single MessageGroupID ? Possibly via `MessageDeduplicationID` ?

Answer (score 0):

Suspect the answer here is just to use one queue per “partition” as SQS pricing works on a per-message basis, not per-queue. If you have a lot of “partitions” then create them programmatically during the stack spin up process (e.g. as part of a CodeBuild script), rather than defining each and every queue in CloudFormation.

Comment: I think this is the approach. Things to consider: a) client distribution across multiple queues , b) how to define the configuration to be easier for each corresponding node consuming from the specific sqs queue